# How much K-meta should I add when racking my cider/wine?

Tags: k-meta, additives, potassium-meta-bisulfite, racking

How much potassium metabisulfite should I add when racking my wine or cider?

Measurements in grams/gallon please.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm not certain about grams per gallon (why are you mixing metric and imperial?). The general rule for wine (and probably cider as well) is one campden tablet or 1/8th tsp of k-meta per gallon.

According to wikipedia one campden tablet typically weighs .44 grams and 10 campden tablets equals 1 tsp of k-meta so I'd guess between .44 and .55 grams of k-meta per gallon. (1/8th of 4.4g is .55g)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Campden_tablets

Adding a little extra won't hurt, especially if your wine or cider is done fermenting.

Answer (score 0):

I generally add 1/4tsp / 5 gallons.  1/4tsp == 1.4 grams so 0.28/gallon.

There are a number of factors (ph, white vs red...), but I've used that measurement for years.